# How to add a rank when a value appears

Tags: excel, ranking, rank

I want to have a rank added to a column when a certain value appears. Below is an example where I have John and Matt who work separate shifts. As they work more and more days, the rank needs to appear beginning from 1 in column c and increases for each shift.
Any help would be great, i do acknowledge this example isn't functional for the query that I have but I need to replicate it over 35 values and need to value their performance over the last 1-5 and 1-10 shifts.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpjpURPjRHXC5qF4C-2fPwPlh7ZP7MzIEacrSq6acaQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `C2` cell and fill down.

```
=IF(B2="","",COUNTIF(B2:$B$10,B2))
```

[image]